# How to share web page with web image to Facebook on iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I want my iPhone app to share a web article to Facebook with an online image using SDK 3.1. I make it share the url of the page and it shows the image on your facebook but doesn't show the image in the share-preview. See photo. It lets me share with image if I add a UIImage, but I don't have a UIImage and I don't want to upload an image every time someone shares, it's already online. I could do all this in SDK 3.0 easily. I don't care if it shares the text of the article or not, I just want the image to show up in the preview and the post and when you click it on Facebook, go to the article page online.

[image: facebook share preview image blank]